# How to convert hydra apiplatform documentation to Swagger specification (OAS3)?

Tags: symfony4, openapi, api-platform.com

My purpose is to call an external hydra api documentation (like https://demo.api-platform.com/docs.jsonld) and convert it on the fly to an OAS 3 (like the one outputed by the command api:openapi:export)

Comment: Can you add some code explaining what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the solution just by calling https://demo.api-platform.com/docs.json :D